# Stretch image on custom camera android

Tags: android, android-camera

I come to you because my custom camera has a big problem : the image is stretched! I have rade that the problem from dimensions but i don't solved it.

If you want pictures to show the problem I will post it

This is my code :

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity{

private SurfaceView surface_view;
private Camera mCamera;
SurfaceHolder.Callback sh_ob = null;
SurfaceHolder surface_holder        = null;
SurfaceHolder.Callback sh_callback  = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    surface_view = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());
    addContentView(surface_view, new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    if (surface_holder == null) {
        surface_holder = surface_view.getHolder();
    }

    sh_callback = my_callback();
    surface_holder.addCallback(sh_callback);
}

SurfaceHolder.Callback my_callback() {
    SurfaceHolder.Callback ob1 = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            mCamera = Camera.open();

            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    };
    return ob1;
}
```

}

Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stretch the surface on full screen; you should set it according to camera aspect ratio. To cover all situations, you need more callbacks. See a nice wrapper class here: http://www.vogella.com/code/de.vogella.android.gallery/src/com/example/android/hcgallery/CameraFragment.html